# AngularJS Data Binding not updating content dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to retrieve data from Google books API - `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes`

Here's the plnkr link- `https://plnkr.co/edit/K4f7CVIeurAUMRzQYMb0?p=preview`

I enter the ISBN number(say: 1234) in the search text, and update the bookList with the response items that I received from google.

I'm trying to iterate over these books using `ng-repeat` but it's not updating.
I need to click on search twice to see the result in `ng-repeat`.

I'm confused why isn't it updating the content dynamically.

See the plnkr link. https://plnkr.co/edit/K4f7CVIeurAUMRzQYMb0?p=preview

Enter 1234 in the search text and click search, won't update in the html.

Click search again, it updates the html with the last response.

Thanks.

Comment: You should not use $.ajax(), use $http instead, basically your approach is wrong.

Comment: also, the ng-repeat should be on the li element, not the ul

Comment: Ok, yeah, I'll do that. But any idea, why it's not updating.

Comment: you use $http like this: `$http.get(url).then(function(response) { first.books = response.data; }, function(error){console.log(error)}`. This way as the scope is evaluated and after the http promise is resolved your repeater will update with the result. Then your li should be `<li ng-repeat="book in first.books">`

Comment: Hi, It worked. But I still didn't get the point of not using $.ajax method here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery to make your call, outside angular $digest. You should use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service instead.

```
$http({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes",
  method: 'GET',
  params: {q:first.inputISBN}
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/VkeBZL8ZF6gfYQ9iQoFv

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Can you please elaborate on your statement about Angular $digest. Or provide any link to read about that.

Comment: Angular needs to be in $digest phase to see that something (in this case array of books) changed. Many things trigger $digest loop, like $http responses, ngClick, $timeout etc. You can also trigger it manually with $scope methods: $apply, $eval, $evalAsync. Then and only then angular starts dirty-checking and reacts to changes.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now.